# white space after my footer issue

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to solve a problem but I´m not having sucess.
 My footer if the content of the site and filled it in the footer is usually at bottom, but if I have few  content on a page footer rises and as I have 2 different footers, and the last footer is white and then I have a huge blank space under my second footer.

I´m trying to find a solution that when I have few content on a page my two footers climb, but without white space at the bottom.

After my second footer I just want the end of the page and not a huge blank space.

I already have tried to do in css on my footer bottom: 0, position: fixed, but so far I´m not having success for my purpose.

Anyone had this problem? Can you give a help?

**My jsfiddle with my example**

http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/wzex4/

**My html:**

```
<footer id="footer-container">


                <section id="footer1">

                    <div id="col">
                    <h1>Newsletter</h1>
                     <ul>
                         <li class="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <a href="#">Write your email</a></li>
                     </ul>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </section>
    <section id="footer2-container">
                    <div id="footer2">
                        <p>&copy; copyright</p>

                    </div>
                </section>
            </footer>
```

**My css:**

```
#footer-container
{
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    background:#ccc; 
    margin-top:15px; 
    bottom:0;   
}

#footer1
{
    width:960px;
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    height:165px; 
}

#footer2-container
{
    width:100%; 
    height:60px; 
    float:left;
    background:#000;
    bottom:0;
    margin-top:15px;
}

#footer2
{
    width:960px; 
    margin:15px auto 0 auto;
}

#footer2 p
{

    color:#fff; 
    font-size:14px; 

}
```

What I´m getting:
[image]

Comment: you can check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzex4/4/)**, i have just added `Position:absolute` to the `#footer-container`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` in your `#footer2-container`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/wzex4/3/)

Comment: Thank you, but I put that now in my #footer2-container and now I have my footer 2 copyright in my index.html  in front of my content, inside body :s

Comment: @John23 Somehow, I can't picture out what is your other problem.

Comment: @John23 Do you means that you want to remove space between #footer1 and #footer2. If you do, just remove margin-top:15px from #footer2-container.
http://jsfiddle.net/wzex4/6/

Answer (score 1):

this is a common problem because the most common workarounds for this are kind of tricky.

You should not use position fixed because in that case the footer will always be on the screen.

If you position absolute the footer to the bottom and give height of html and body as 100%, whereas the content (in a container) gets padding-bottom the size of the footer so that if content is more it should not overlap.

Here's how I deal with it:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    padding-bottom: 20px; /* if your footer height is 20px including paddings and margins */
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```